# How to create Angular2 single file for plunker?

Tags: typescript, angular, plunker

I'm using [such](http://plnkr.co/edit/OhGOKXWYLpiDKMSZmcoe?p=preview) plunker like a starter for Angular2. But it's extremely slow. Mostly because it tries to transpile it each time when on reload:

```
var angularVersion = '2.0.0-rc.4';

System.config({
  baseUrl: '/',
  paths: {
    'npmcdn:*': 'https://npmcdn.com/*'
  }
});

System.config({
  transpiler: 'typescript', 
  typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true },

  meta: {
    '*': {
      deps: [ 'zone.js', 'reflect-metadata' ]
    }
  }
});

System.config({
  packageConfigPaths: [
    "npmcdn:@*/*/package.json"
  ],

  map: {
    '@angular/core': 'npmcdn:@angular/core@'+angularVersion,
    '@angular/compiler': 'npmcdn:@angular/compiler@'+angularVersion,
    '@angular/common': 'npmcdn:@angular/common@'+angularVersion,
    '@angular/platform-browser': 'npmcdn:@angular/platform-browser@'+angularVersion,
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npmcdn:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@'+angularVersion,
    'rxjs': 'npmcdn:rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6',
    'zone.js': 'npmcdn:zone.js@0.6.12',
    'reflect-metadata': 'npmcdn:reflect-metadata@0.1.3',
    "crypto": "@empty"
  },

  packages: {
    'app': {
      defaultExtension: 'ts',
      main: './index.ts'
    }
  }
});
```

I'm thinking about **idea of precompiling kind of single file bundle** with all vendor parts of Angular2 to make it faster and transpile only code of you application but not libraries.

Is there already a solution for it?

Comment: Docs already stated that [*Do not transpile in the browser during development or for production.*](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#transpiling-in-the-browser)

Comment: I need it also for demo in plunker with possibility to make quick changes

Answer (score 0):

The Angular2 quickstart use aggregated UMD module. You should have a look at the [live demo](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/ts/plnkr.html).
It changes the SystemJS configuration to load the UMD module instead of each individual file. Here is the important part of the file.

```
ngPackageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {

    // Bundled (~40 requests):
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };

    // Individual files (~300 requests):
    //packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  });
```